# Twilio - Could not decode response body as JSON. This likely indicates a 500 server error

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am using Twilio Rest API to pull some usage logs

```
foreach ($client->account->usage_records->last_month as $record) {
    if ($record->count > 0) {
        $call_record[] = array(
            'category' => $record->category,
            'count' => $record->count,
            'usage' => $record->usage,
            'price'=>$record->price,
            'price_unit'=>$record->price_unit
        );
    }
}
```

It is giving me this error:
**Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'Could not decode response body as JSON. This likely indicates a 500 server error' in /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php:28**

I tried wrapping the code inside a try catch like this

```
try {
    // Loop over the list of records and echo a property for each one
    foreach ($client->account->usage_records->last_month as $record) {
        if ($record->count > 0) {
            $call_record[] = array(
                'category' => $record->category,
                'count' => $record->count,
                'usage' => $record->usage,
                'price'=>$record->price,
                'price_unit'=>$record->price_unit
            );
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

and I was able to get some usage data back but not all. I am missing things like calls-outbound which I know for sure we have some. So I think it breaks trying to fetch some categories and that is why it is trowing the error, but that is just a really wild guess. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Here is the stack-trace:

```
Stack trace:
**0 /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php(265): Base_Services_Twilio-&gt;_processResponse(Array)
1 /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php(236): Base_Services_Twilio-&gt;_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...', 1)
2 /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(120): Base_Services_Twilio-&gt;retrieveData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array, true)
3 /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(179): Services_Twilio_ListResource-&gt;getPage(1, 50, Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...')
4 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_ListResource-&gt;getPageGenerator(1, 50,  in /Users/enmanuelcorvo/development/demos/twilio_usage/vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio.php on line 287**
```

Comment: Certificate issues with curl? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/issues/226

Comment: If this is a 500 error on Twilio's side, then I would raise this with our help team. Just email them at help@twilio.com and give them all the detail.

Comment: I was recommended to re install Curl by Twilio support. Will give that a try.

Comment: How to reinstall Curl? I am using it on XAMPP

Comment: Is there a way to get around this when developing on a localhost with something like XAMPP or WAMP/MAMP?

Comment: Guys get off MAMP/XAMPP/WAMP go to vagrant, much better

Comment: I agree tried it and liked it, but node basically broke windows (really long deep directories) so until I'm on a mac not really an option :(

Comment: @Xtremefaith well my next advise is to get off Windows lol I don't know much about setting up MAMP I always found it extremely complicated. Good luck hope you can find some help

Answer (score 0):

Ross McKay has an article that suggest the issue is with the installation of PHP. As he puts it:

> *The error is caused by not having an up-to-date bundle of CA root certificates. This is typically a text file with a bunch of cryptographic signatures that curl uses to verify a host’s SSL certificate. You need to make sure that your installation of PHP has one of these files, and that it’s up to date.*

**[Simply download the the latest CA root certificate bundle from here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)**

And then within your `php.ini` file look for a section called `[curl]` (near the bottom in my case), and set your `curl.cainfo` according to where you place the `cacert.pem`, like so:

```
curl.cainfo=D:\Bitnami\wampstack\php\cacert.pem
```

Works like a charm!

**Reference:**

http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by an incorrect entry of the accountSID and AuthToken. Make sure they're formatted as follows:

```
$AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";
```

Replace with your accountSid and AuthToken found at [www.twilio.com/Console](http://www.twilio.com/Console)